# Connect to Express server using it's IP address

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server, ip

Wanted to know if it's possible to connect to an express server using that servers UP address. If it is how would you do it?(some code examples would be very appreciated)

Comment: As opposed to connecting using...?

Comment: I'm assuming you mean `IP` address, not `UP` address.

Answer (score 0):

Same as with any http server.   This is not specific to Express at all.  It's just browsers and TCP.

From a browser, you would just type:

```
http://192.168.1.100/somePath
```

Where you put in the IP address of the server and the desired path for the URL.

---

If you're connecting programmatically, you'd have to tell us what client environment you're using so we could offer a relevant exampale.  All TCP connections are fundamentally connecting via the IP address (that's how TCP connections work).

Some APIs allow you to use the DNS name and then the first step under the covers of the API is to look up the IP address that corresponds to that DNS name and then connect to the IP address.

> Wanted to know if it's possible to connect to an express server using that servers IP address.

Yes, that's actually the only way to connect to any server that uses TCP as the transport.  All TCP connections are made from one IP address to another IP address.

Comment: actually I was going to try connect several regular computers(servers) together to create a decentralized network so it`s possible to accesses a express server remotely just using it`s IP even if it`s running on a regular desktop computer

Comment: @Isaacfenech - It drives us kind of nuts when you post a question that doesn't contain the real question you mean to ask about and then you progressively disclose the real question later in comments.  If that architecture is what you mean to ask about, then write a new question that completely describes the REAL problem you're asking about.  Meanwhile, I think we've answered what you originally asked here and you shouldn't be turning that into another question by adding more information in comments.  stack overflow is a q&a site (you ask a question, we try to answer it), not a discussion site.

Comment: @Isaacfenech - Desktop computers are usually behind firewalls so typically cannot be directly connected to from the internet and typically don't have public IP addresses either.  Further discussion of that topic should be in a new question, not here.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it's appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Just use the IP address in place of where you would put localhost or the domain.

For example:

- https://www.google.com/ -> https://216.58.217.164/
- https://localhost/hello.html -> https://127.0.0.1/hello.html
- https://localhost:8080/ -> https://127.0.0.1:8080/

I can add a code sample if you add your current code to the question or say what you are using to make the connection.